# How can to get data from related model in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have next **models**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Statistic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='statistics')
    clicks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

and **serializers**

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'ip_address']


class UserStatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Statistic
```

How can I get in `Response` data in following format:

```
{
  'user_data': {
      'id': 1, 'first_name': 'name', ...,
      'statistics': [
          {'id': 1, 'clicks': 100},
          {'id': 3, 'clicks': 550}
      ]
}
```

I go to the link `/api/v1/users/<int:pk>/` and call next function:

```
class UserDetailStatisticApiView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = ???
    serializer_class = ???
```

Thnx for help

Comment: There seems to be an error with your relations. Or do you really want to return all Statisctics of all users in your Response?

Comment: No, I want to return data of user (from `<pk>`), and all his statistics.

Comment: Then why do you need a different model for that? I mean why you did not put clicks field to User model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**serializers**

```
class StatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Statistic
        fields = ['date', 'clicks', 'page_views']


class UserStatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    statistics = StatisticSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'ip_address', 'statistics'
        ]
```

**views**

```
class UserDetailStatisticApiView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserStatisticSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

View

```
class UserDetailStatisticApiView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer
```

Serializers

```
class UserStatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Statistic
        fields = '__all__'


class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    statistics = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'statistics']
    
    def get_statistics(self,obj):
        statistics = Statistic.objects.filter(user=obj)
        return  UserStatisticSerializer(statistics, many=True).data
```

Comment: how this answer covers 'statistics': {[
          {'id': 1, 'clicks': 100},
          {'id': 3, 'clicks': 550}
      ]}
?

Comment: @engin_ipek just need to add `fields` attribute to `UserStatisticSerializer`